# Apex Trigger test Class Issue; No Standard Price Defined

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, before-trigger

Here is my Apex Trigger

```
trigger ProductNameTrigger on QuoteLineItem (before insert) {
    list<QuoteLineItem> plist = new list<QuoteLineItem>();
    for(quotelineitem q : [select id, Product2.name, product2id, Product2_Name__c from QuoteLineItem where id =:trigger.new]){
        q.Product2_Name__c = q.Product2.name;
        plist.add(q);
    }
    update plist;
}
```

and here is my test class

```
private static testMethod void testTrig(){
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity(name='testOp', StageName='Closed', CloseDate=date.today());
    insert o;
    Product2 prodTest = new Product2(Name = 'testProduct', StandardPrice=20);
    insert prodTest;
    Quote quoteTest = new Quote(OpportunityId = o.id);
    quoteTest.name = 'testQuote';
    insert quoteTest;
    PriceBook2 pbook = new PriceBook2(name='testBook');
    insert pbook;
    PriceBookEntry entry = new PriceBookEntry( Product2Id=prodTese.id, UnitPrice=0, PriceBook2Id=pbook.id, UseStandardPrice=true);
    insert entry;

    QuoteLineItem q = new QuoteLineItem(Product2Id = prodTest.id, PriceBookEntryId=entry.id, Quantity=0, UnitPrice=entry.UnitPrice);
    insert q;

    System.assertEquals(prodTest.name, q.Product2_Name__c);
}
```

and I am getting an Error that states

> First exception on row 0; first error: STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED, No
>   standard price defined for this product: []

Any Idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that when using custom pricebooks (`pBook`), before you can add a PBE (PricebookEntry) for that product | pricebook combination, you must first insert a PBE for the same product | standard Pricebook combination

The standard pricebook's id can be found from `Test.getStandardPricebookId()`.  You do not create a standard pricebook in the testmethod

You'll need something like:

```
PriceBookEntry[] entryList = new List<PriceBookEntry> {
    new PricebookEntry( Product2Id=prodTese.id, UnitPrice=0,
                        PriceBook2Id=Test.getStandardPricebookId(), // **
                        UseStandardPrice=false,isActive=true),
    new PricebookEntry( Product2Id=prodTese.id, UnitPrice=0, 
                        PriceBook2Id=pbook.id, 
                        UseStandardPrice=true,isActive=true)
    };
insert entryList;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! haven't checked to see if this has worked yet I'll get back to you

Comment: The test class works now, but the PriceBook2_Name__c is null instead of 'testProd' so i assume something is incorrect with my trigger

Comment: Cool; there's not enough  posted to diagnose `pricebook2_name__c` issue; hopefully, you'll figure this out but you can file a new question if still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Few issues to mention

Your trigger is for `before insert` of `QuoteLineItem` records. So you can't really query out QuoteLintItems of Trigger.new in line

```
for(quotelineitem q : [select id, Product2.name, product2id, Product2_Name__c from QuoteLineItem where id =:trigger.new])
```

because records in Trigger.new don't exist in the database yet.

And in a `before insert` trigger, you don't have to specifically update the record, you just have to code the changes you want to happen, and they will be reflected in the inserted records.

So if all you want to do in the trigger is to change the records' `Product2_Name__c` field, your trigger should change as

```
trigger ProductNameTrigger on QuoteLineItem (before insert) {
    List<Id> product2Ids = new List<Id>();
    for(quotelineitem q : Trigger.new){
        product2Ids.add(q.Product2Id);
    }
    Map<Id, Product2> product2Map = new Map<Id, Product2>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :product2Ids]);

    for(quotelineitem q : Trigger.new) {
         if(product2Map.containsKey(q.Product2Id)) {
             q.Product2_Name__c = product2Map.get(q.Product2Id).Name;
         }
    }
}
```

So back to your error, check if there is `StandardPrice` is a valid field name for `Product2` record.

Comment: Thank you for the help with the Trigger! also there is no Standard Price field for the Product2 object

Comment: That's why you are getting the error. So all your issues are solved now?

Comment: No i took it out but I am still getting the error

Comment: Heres the full error if it helps 'Class.testProdNameTrigger.testTrig: line 14, column 1
13:07:08.525 (4525387670)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED, No standard price defined for this product: []'